# Translate links in Drupal menu page

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I have a maybe rather silly question. I have a test website and a live website (both Drupal 7)

In the test website I have setup translations for my main-menu using the module "Menu Translation" (it is a sub-module of [i18n](https://drupal.org/project/i18n)) and at mydomain.com/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu I see a third column with the option to "translate" the menu options in the first column.

At my live website I want to do the same, but can't figure out what setting I have to change in order to get these " translate" links appear in the same page?

The settings in the testwebsite are done more than half a year ago and  I cant remember how I did that. The Multilangual option -> Translate and Localize is set for the main-menu on both sites.

This is what my live website looks like [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0L2y.jpg
 This is what my test website looks like [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BvNz.jpg

I assume that this has nothing to do with the "reset" link? (no idea what the purpose of that link is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked an Drupal website design company which searched for the difference between live and test site. The solution was that the permissions for my own role as designated admin (not the main admin role) where not set the same regarding: under String translation the settings for "Translate user-defined strings" and "Translate admin strings" must be enabled in order to show the "translate" column, which I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In General Usage of Contributed Modules first steps to use any module is

- Read Documentation of Project Page in D.O . You will find the link in the right side bar.

[image]

- Readme or Install files inside Module Folder
- Still if you are unable to figure out.. Visit .module file and focus on hook_menu implementation which lists menu paths as keys of $items array.. By visiting those pages you will get a chance to see configuration pages given by that particular module.

In your case

- Enable i18n_menu module which has following module dependencies. I enabled using drush which automatically downloads and enabled below modules. In your case make sure below modules are present in your instance.

The following extensions will be enabled: i18n_menu, i18n_translation, i18n_string, variable, locale, i18n

- Once you enable you can see "Translate" setting in any menu page. I just verified no other changes are required. Just clear cache once you enable module in case.

[image]

Comment: Hi Anil Sagar, thanks for you reply. Regarding reading the documentation: I found there is no specific documentation of the menu translation submodule, there isn't even a separate page of that submodule. Visiting .module file en focusing on hook_menu implementation requires php knowledge(?) which I can't read, sorry i'm no programmer and I hope this is not required to setup Drupal.   I searched for the enabled i18n modules, and think the modules itself do not present themselves under this name in my module list? (Searching in module list and typing i18n doesn't give me a result).

Comment: I think the modules present themselves under the names: "menu translation", "string translation", "variable translation"etc (which are all enabled)